# Creating Environment-specific configuration files in VS-2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, msbuild, build-automation

I'm trying to create environment specific configurations in Visual Studio 2010 and can't get the transformations to occur for anything other then the **App.config**. Here is an example of my scenario:

- Added a configuration file in my project (*e.g. Configs\Log4Net.config*). The file is set to "Content" and "Copy Always"

> ```
> <log4net>
>   <root>
>     <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
>     <level value="DEBUG" />
>   </root>
>   <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
>   ...
>   </appender>
> </log4net>
> ```

- Added a transformation configuration file (*e.g. Configs\Log4Net.Release.config*)

> ```
> <log4net xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
>   <root>
>     <level value="WARN" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="XPath(log4net/root/level[@value!='WARN'])" />
>   </root>
> </log4net>
> ```

- Modified the VS Project file to include the following target

> ```
> <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" 
>            AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
>
> <Target Name="AfterPublish" Condition="exists('Configs\Log4Net.$(Configuration).config')">
>   <TransformXml Source="Configs\Log4Net.config" 
>                 Destination="$(OutputPath)\Configs\Log4Net.config" 
>                 Transform="Configs\Log4Net.$(Configuration).config" />
> </Target>
> ```

I've followed a similar pattern for the App.config and that works fine, but this one does not appear to work. My expectation is that when I do a **Release** build, the log level should be set to **WARN**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [XmlPreprocess tool](http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/) for config files manipulation. It is using one mapping file for multiple environments. You can edit mapping file by Excel. It is very easy to use.

Try to replace your TransformXml task with Exec task and call XmlPreprocess tool.